# What does the phrase "说不好比起~" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw this on a reviewer's video, but I'm not sure if I understand the meaning or how you would parse it in English?

I didn't catch everything the speaker said but I remember;

> 说不好比起[name of character C]也

From context it seems like the speaker was comparing someone he's recently met (A) to two others (B and C), he said A was not like B, and then he says A is "说不好比起[name of character C]也".

Answer (score 1):

- '说不好' is a variant of '说不定' (can't state with certainty= **may be**)
- '比起' means 'compare to'
- '也' in this context means 'even'

"说不好比起 C 也" = "May be even(?) compare to C"

*It is an incomplete sentence, we don't know what quality is being compared between B and C*

The following would be a complete sentence:

> "[**说不好**]比起 C 也好不了多少" - "[**May**] not even [**be**] any better  compare to C"
>
> 好不了多少= not even any better

Answer (score 0):

should add a comma: 说不好, 比起C....

比起：compare to/with

说不好=不好说 means "it's hard to tell".

I figure the implication here is the speaker is hard to tell the differences between A and C; he may be able to identify the differences but not knowing how to tell/describe them, or just simply unable to identify any.